Error installing JavaScript language in GraalVM: Unsupported GraalVM version
Downloading: Component catalog from www.graalvm.org
Could not load channel https://www.graalvm.org/component-catalog/graal-updater-component-catalog.properties: Unsupported GraalVM version: 22.1.0.1, platform windows/amd64
Error: Unsupported GraalVM version: 22.1.0.1, platform windows/amd64
I have found this error as well.
ERROR! No language and polyglot implementation was found on the classpath. Make sure a language is added to the classpath (e.g., native-image --language:js).
This error occurred in the context of using GraalVM's native-image tool to ahead-of-time compile Java applications into native executables. The error suggests that the tool couldn't find any language implementations on the classpath, specifically JavaScript (js).
Troubleshooting Steps:
Attempted Solution: I tried to run gu install js to install JavaScript, but it resulted in the above error message.
GraalVM Version: My GraalVM version is 22.1.0.1, and I'm using the Windows platform (windows/amd64).
Documentation Review: I checked the GraalVM documentation, which indicates that JavaScript is no longer installed by default since GraalVM 22.1.0.1.
Error Analysis: The error suggests that the GraalVM version and platform are unsupported when trying to load the component catalog for gu install js.
Request for Assistance:
I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue and successfully install the JavaScript language in GraalVM version 22.1.0.1 on the Windows platform.
I need a solution which help me out the solution work with following way:
mvn gluonfx:build -P windows
gluonfx:runagent -P windows
or
with jenkins build
Additional Notes:
Are there alternative methods to install JavaScript in GraalVM 22.1.0.1?
Has anyone encountered a similar issue with unsupported GraalVM versions, and if so, how was it resolved?
I have found stackoverflow link but unable to get the solution
A language with id 'js' is not installed. Installed languages are: [] GraavlVM 17
